# Send Mail with AppleScript without showing anything onto the screen

Tags: applescript

how is it possible to send an email with apple mail into osx based onto an AppleScript without showing anything onto the screen.

Based on a rule, an AppleScript is executed in another application that automatically sends several e-mails.

Something is briefly displayed on the screen for about half a second for each email that is sent. I assume that this is the email that is being sent. As a result, it flickers on the screen several times for every 10 emails.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It is not a notification. It looks like the window for writing a new mail will be opened of about 200 ms.

Comment: If you're still having the problem, can you use (or borrow) a fancy mobile phone that allows slow motion video recording and use that to confirm for us the dialog / window that is being displayed, please?